# Array element can't access by index

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have an array in $this->request->data object:

```
Array
(
    [Reseller] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan 
            [mobile] => 01673050495
            [email] => kuet.absb@yahoo.com
        )

)
```

So I want to access id as usual : `$this->request->data['Reseller']['id'];`
But it shows undefined index `Reseller`. The following works fine :

```
$requestData = $this->request->data;
pr($requestData['Reseller']);
```

gives:

```
 Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Abdus Sattar Bhuiyan 
            [mobile] => 01673050495
            [email] => kuet.absb@yahoo.com
        )
```

And when I try to show id again by pr($requestData['Reseller']['id']); it shows undefined index `Reseller` again. And the following works again:
$data = $requestData['Reseller'];
pr($data['id']);

My pr() function is:

```
function pr($data){
echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';
}
```

**My full php code:**

```
function changePersonalInfo() {
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $this->render('nothing');
        $this->loadModel('Reseller');
        $requestData =$this->request->data;
        $data = $requestData['Reseller'];
        pr($data['id']); exit;
        $this->Reseller->id = $this->request->data['Reseller']['id'];
        $this->Reseller->save($this->request->data['Reseller']);

        $msg = ' <div class="alert alert-success">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                                <strong>Chanes Saved</strong> 
                            </div>';


        $return['msg'] = $msg;
        $reseller = $this->Reseller->findById($this->Reseller->id);
        $return['reseller'] = $reseller['Reseller'];
        $result = json_encode($return);
        echo $result;
    }
```

It is strange! The requested data is posted by ajax request as follows:

```
function saveData(formid, processUrl, updateSection) {

    $(formid).submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //  Abort any pending request

        var fields = "input, select, button, textarea";
        var $form = $(this);
        var $inputs = $form.find(fields);
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
      var  request = $.ajax({
            url: processUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "post",
            data: serializedData
        });
        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(
                    "The following error occurred: " +
                    textStatus, errorThrown
                    );

        });
        request.always(function () {
            // Reenable the inputs
            $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $(updateSection+' .bubblingG').fadeOut(2000,function(){
                 $(updateSection).before(response.msg);
                 if(updateSection == "#personalInfo"){
                    $('#avatar #ResellerEmail').val(response.reseller.email);
                 }
            });//({visibility: 'hidden'}, 2000, 'linear');//css("visibility", "hidden");

        });

        // Prevent default posting of form
//        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

This problem makes me cry. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you `print_r($requestData)`?

Comment: just wondering why you are doing `$this->request->data['Reseller']['id'];` instead of `$this->request->data->Reseller->id;`?

Comment: Yes. I can print this array

Comment: Hmm. Try to add `[0]` between `Reseller` and `id`

Comment: Show please your PHP code, how you get $requestData?

Comment: I edit my question and add full php code.@mnv
I inspect $this->request->data as an array not object @sean